# One-way ANOVA: Concluding one true differences without any post-hoc tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, repeated-measures

Let's say that I run a one-way ANOVA with 3+ levels and that it comes out significant. Can I then, from this result alone, conclude that *at least* the two sample means that differs the most in my data set actually differs with regard to their true mean?

Comment: Well, no for a number of reasons; for example what if the two that are most different in sample mean also have the smallest $n_i$? I think there's a near duplicate or two on site.

Comment: @Glen_b Good point! I would love to hear the other reasons as well :)